# In Azure how can multiple Web Roles read from the same Lucene.net index that is stored in Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, lucene.net, azure-blob-storage

In Azure how can multiple Web Roles read from the same Lucene.net index that is stored in Blob Storage?

BTW - I'm using the **Lucene.Net.Store.Azure** library from NuGet to persist my Lucene.net index to Azure Blob Storage.

The problem I'm encountering is outlined below in the following diagram:

[image]

One idea I had was to ensure that each of my Web Roles acted in "read only" mode, and did not ever write to the index.  I could create a separate Worker Role to the writing.  I'm not sure if that would work though.

Another idea I had was to make multiple copies of the index; one for each Web Role.  It seems kind of inefficient though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first idea is good.  I would also suggest implementing a separate worker role to write to the index.  Since Azure SLA required two servers per any role, you can implementing a queuing or blob leasing mechanism to ensure that two workers do not try to write to the index at the same time.